# Why is my treeview not showing in GUI on Repl.it (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, treeview, replit

Can anyone see why my tree view isn't showing on my app when I run it in repl.it. The GUI shows and the first frame. But I can't get the frame for the treeview or the actual treeview data to show. I'm trying to add the treeframe under the data entry frame ("Divisions") in the root window.  I've got the data entry area in the root on row 0 and the treeview frame on row 1.  So I don't understand why it's not showing. Here is the code minus most of the functions:

```
#Functions

def get_existing_values(table_name):
  conn = sqlite3.connect('tbf.db')
  c = conn.cursor()
  c.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + table_name)
  existing_values = c.fetchall()
  conn.close()
  return existing_values

#Program Start
initialConnection()

root = Tk()
root.title("TBF Divisions Entry Form")
root.geometry("600x500")

frame = LabelFrame(root, text="TBF Divisions", padx=10, pady=10)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

divisionCodeLabel = Label(frame, text="Division Code")
divisionCodeLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

divisionCodeEntry = Entry(frame, width=15)
divisionCodeEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

divisionDescriptionLabel = Label(frame, text="Division Description")
divisionDescriptionLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
divisionDescriptionEntry = Entry(frame, width=25)
divisionDescriptionEntry.grid(row=0, column=3)

treeFrame = LabelFrame(root, text="Divisions Table", padx=10, pady=10)
frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
tree = ttk.Treeview(treeFrame,
                    columns=("Division Code", "Description"),
                    show="headings",
                    height=5)
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

tree.heading("Division Code", text="Division Code")
tree.heading("Description", text="Division Description")
tree.column("Division Code", width=100)
tree.column("Description", width=100)


existing_values = get_existing_values("divisions")
print(existing_values)

count=0
    for value in existing_values:
        tree.insert("", "end", iid=count, values=(value[0], value[1]))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out....I didn't pack the treeFrame properly.  I typed "frame.pack()" instead of "treeFrame.pack()".  Once I made that correct it worked.

Thought about deleting this but decided to leave it up incase anyone else could find it useful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).